# Compiling python packages for electron js

Tags: javascript, python, electron

So my question is pretty straight forward. I am using Electron js and python to create a desktop application. The problem I have though is that the application would make use of a couple of python packages and selenium. Is there a way to compile those packages in such a way that the user of the desktop app wont need to install python and the packages on their system to use the desktop app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [py2exe](https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/) and [py2app](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for Windows and Mac. Linux and MacOS should already have python installed though. These allow you to make executable python applications that do not require python to be installed on the users' computer.

I hope this helped :)